# Problemas con refactor en Java/Spring con Apache

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache

les comento, tengo que refactorizar partes de un codigo porque se actualizaron las librerías de Springboot a 2.7.2 y Apache Camel a 3.16.0, pero estoy teniendo problemas.

El código que les pongo ahora en la versión anterior funcionaba perfecto:

```
BindyDataFormat bindy = new BindyDataFormat();
bindy.setClassType(Someclass.class);
bindy.setLocale("en");
bindy.setType(BindyType.Csv);
```

El problema es que ahora el ultimo comando (bindy.setType()) no permite el ingreso de un type (como esta puesto, BindyType.Csv), sino que tiene que recibir si o si un String.

Ahora muestra **setType()** con error y muestra este error:

**"The method setType(String) in the type BindyDataFormat is not applicable for the arguments (BindyType)"**

Es decir, que ya no acepta el BindyType.Csv que le enviabamos antes.

¿Alguien sabe como tendría que llenarlo para que quede CSV como antes? En este entorno no puedo hacer pruebas ni compilar... ¿seria un string tipo ponerlo asi: "csv" o "Csv"??

Se los agradecería mucho!!

(la libreria es org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.BindyDataFormat)

gracias!

Comment: Qué error sale cuando lo usas así como está? Por qué dices que no lo permite? Cuál es el error o la traza de error? Ve a [edit] la pregunta y complétala, por favor

Answer (score 0):

El código fuente de la clase que estás usando [muestra](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-core-model/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/BindyDataFormat.java) que ese atributo `type` se valida contra el mismo [`BindyType`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-core-model/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/BindyType.java) de toda la vida.

Lo que siempre ha estado desde que existe la clase BindyDataFormat es que `setType` recibe un String. Así pues, tu código nunca "lo hizo bien".

Como ya viste el Enum, bien podrías usar `BindyType.Csv.name()` para pasarle el valor `Csv` como String sin quemarlo y que siga dependiendo de la implementación de Camel.

Comment: O sea que podria quedar asi: bindy.setType(BindyType.Csv.name()); ??? ¿Asi se le puede setear un tipo?

Comment: @LeanderJS pruébalo :)